# How do i improve my code to load images from remote server more effiecintly without UI lag?

Tags: java, android

The adapter provides data for a listview. But when you scroll up and down, it shows old images and takes a couple of seconds to finish loading the images. This is true when you open the view for the first time.

```
public class BooksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Books> {


    public BooksAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Books> word) {
        super(context, 0, word);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }


        // Get the {@link AndroidFlavor} object located at this position in the list
        Books currentbook = getItem(position);


        TextView bookView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.bookTittle);
        String booktitle = currentbook.getBookName();
        bookView.setText(booktitle);

        TextView authorView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.authorname);
        String authorname = currentbook.getAuthorName();
        authorView.setText(authorname);

        ImageView imageurl = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        String imagelink = currentbook.getImageLink();

        ImageAsyncTask task = new ImageAsyncTask(imageurl);
        task.execute(imagelink);


        return listItemView;

    }

    private class ImageAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        private ImageView img;

        ImageAsyncTask(ImageView img) {
            this.img = img;
        }


        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {

            URL url = null;
            Bitmap bmp = null;

            try {
                url = new URL(urls[0]);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with creating URL ", e);
            }
            try {
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the earthquake JSON results.", e);
            }

            return bmp;


        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap data) {
            this.img.setImageBitmap(data);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Question about codereview (improve working code) should be ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: okay, sorry.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recomend to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for this task and dont invent bicycle. You can just call `GlideApp.with(this).load("http://url.com").into(imageView);` and Glide will do all work for you.

Comment: i think its Glide.with(c)
                .load(imagelink)
                .into(imageurl);

Answer (score 1):

Glide with default image if actual image not loaded from the server.
Place this in app.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Use it like,

```
Glide.with(this)
                .load("your_image_url")
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        Log.d("d", "onResourceReady");


                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .error("your_default_image")// placed in drawable
                .into("your_target_view");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

User Picasso best way to display image even you can set default image when image is loading see below example..

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.default_image).into(imageView);
```

compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0' just add into build.gradle

Comment: i am not saying glide works worse but i  am sharing my experience with picasso.